# Configure sam local start-api to send PUT request payloads only

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

*My main question is:*
**How can I configure SAM to create API endpoints without Lambda Proxy Integration?**

*Details:*
I am trying to test an API Gateway + Lambda deployment locally. The Lambda function I have specified is expecting to receive the payload of `PUT` requests on `/some-endpoint` as the `event` when invoked. This is the behavior on AWS when creating this endpoint without Lambda Proxy Integration.

However, it seems that `sam local start-api` defaults to using Proxy Integration; obviously, this results in an `event` with unexpected structure for my Lambda. I just tried changing the method to GET, and still see Proxy Integration behavior, so it's not PUT-specific.

I know that the local API Gateway and Lambda are communicating and that my function is otherwise working as I want when I test Lambda with `sam local invoke -e sample-payload.json`.

I haven't tried `sam deploy` to know if this is unique to `sam local` or the general behavior of SAM-specified endpoints.

**Clarification:** `sam local` and my Lambda code are functioning, no errors aside from those arising from the unexpected `event` format due to `sam` defaulting to Lambda Proxy Integration. The SAM documentation says nothing about configuring the PUT method handling, but maybe someone here can help.

Roughly, my Lambda function (event) is expecting `event` to be the JSON payload of PUT requests, eg

```py
{"id": "user123"}
```

If I use the AWS console to set up the API Gateway `/some-endpoint` resource's PUT method, and *do not make this endpoint with Lambda Proxy Integration* then API Gateway passes along just the body/payload, as above.

When I use `sam local start-api` based on the YAML above, then send a PUT to `http://localhost:3000/some-endpoint`, the request makes it to my Lambda function just fine, but I get the `event` is now formatted as Proxy Integration. So, `event` now looks like

```py
{"body": '{"id": "abc123"}', "httpMethod": "GET", ...}
```

and I have to parse the `"body"` to get the payload I want.

Ultimately I could change the code to expect Proxy Integration instead, but ideally `sam local start-api` could send just payloads.

---

For a minimal example of this:

**Lambda Python 3.8 script** returning the event for illustration.

`my_function.py`

```py
import json


def handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(event)
    }
```

SAM file, `template.yml`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: my_function.handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      CodeUri: .
      Policies: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
      Role: 
      Events:
        Api1:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /some-endpoint
            Method: PUT
```

And a payload to PUT.
`id-event.json`

```
{"id": "user123"}
```

What I'm looking for is the response of a PUT to `localhost:3000/some-endpoint` to be `{"id": "user123"}`.

Comment: Whats the error when you `sam local start-api` and start sending PUT requests to it?

Comment: There's no code error. SAM just isn't configuring the local API Gateway to Lambda connection as I would like. I'll update the post to reflect this.

Comment: Ok,  I still am having a hard time understanding what you are expecting vs observed.  When I `sam local start-api` it says something like `Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/` and I use that as the api for my local vue app. Do you get that too?  (disclaimer: I'm nowhere near an expert at aws-sam,  just an average SO user, I hope)

Comment: Thanks for your continued help! I see the same thing, I can PUT just fine to `http://127.0.01:3000/some-endpoint`, but the actual event passed along to Lambda isn't the same as what you can do using the AWS API Gateway console directly (just sending payload, not the entire header/method/etc. See my updated question.

Comment: yea, I think its always different when you `sam local start-api`. Not 100% tho.

Comment: I have the same issue. 
I discovered the reason why `start-api` generate the payload 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging-python.html
`sam local start-api -d 5890` 
is the same as 
`sam local generate-event apigateway aws-proxy | sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction -d 5890`

Comment: same problem! POST and PUT are not working as expected